# How to make "the smooth table" in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have android screen and i want copy it to swiftui ios screen.

Android:
[image: text are smooth, gravity left + top. Baseline in top]

iOS:
[image]

But i try to make it in swiftui. How you see text dont have baseline and gravity parameters, how i make it in android. Help me please make equivalent simple screen.

My swiftui code:

```
struct WeatherView: View {
    var weather: WeatherMainModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Description: \(weather.weather[0].component3())")
                Text("Visibility: \(weather.visibility) meters")
                Text("Main: \(weather.weather[0].main)")
            }
            VStack {
                Text("Temperature Data")
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Temperature: \(temperatureString(value: weather.mainData.temperature))")
                                .font(.system(size: 15))
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("Temperature fels like: \(temperatureString(value: weather.mainData.temperatureFeelsLike))")
                                .font(.system(size: 15))
                            Spacer()
                        }

                    }
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Temperature max: \(temperatureString(value: weather.mainData.temperatureMax))")
                                .font(.system(size: 15))
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("Temperature min: \(temperatureString(value: weather.mainData.temperatureMin))")
                                .font(.system(size: 15))
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(.horizontal, 5)
            }.cornerRadius(10)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.horizontal)
    }

    private func temperatureString(value: Float) -> String {
        return String(format: "%.2f", value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second screen texts differ from first one, but I assume you wanted something like below (of corse padding/spacing/fonts can be tuned)

Prepared with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Description")
            Text("Visibility")
            Text("main")
            VStack {
                Text("Temperature Data")
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text("Temperature: 38 dsa das das das da sd")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("Temperature Max: 38")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text("Temperature fels like: 38")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("Temperature Min: 38")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }.padding(.top)
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.horizontal, 8)
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome and simply! Thank you very much!